# Checking translation of "optimus magister is fuit qui scivit quid discipuli peterent: auxilium"

Tags: translation-check

I would like to know if this sentence is correct:

> optimus magister is fuit qui scivit quid discipuli peterent: auxilium

What I would like to say in English is: "The best teacher was the one who knew what students were looking for: help".

I don't know what the colon in Latin was. Thus I used the English punctuation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Scivit* should be subjunctive *sciret*, since (on the most natural reading) this is a relative clause of characteristic: whoever knew what students were looking for, that person was the best teacher.

I'm doubtful about the colon with *auxilium*. My sense is that Latin prose doesn't generally use this construction in the way that English does, but would be more likely to use something like a "namely" instead. You could use *id est* for that.

You might consider changing *fuit* to imperfect *erat*, but that depends on how you want to present the aspect of this sentence and on the context.

*Is* could optionally be left out -- grammatically the sentence is fine either way, but the rhythm may be a bit better without it.

Finally, I would change the order of the indirect question clause to *quid peterent discipuli*, which to me sounds better.

So: *Optimus magister (is) fuit/erat qui sciret quid peterent discipuli, id est auxilium*.